# need to create a TTL (time-to-live) feature during create table in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, schema, ttl

I am using nodejs with dynamodb. I need to add TTL feature in my code. When i am adding below code in my schema file and try to create table its give below error. Also my **timetolive** field is not creating on the table too.

```
{
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: 'foo', AttributeType: 'S' },
    { AttributeName: 'baar', AttributeType: 'N' },
    { AttributeName: 'timetolive', AttributeType: 'N' }
  ],
  KeySchema: [
    { AttributeName: 'foo', KeyType: 'HASH' },
    { AttributeName: 'baar', KeyType: 'RANGE' }
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: { ReadCapacityUnits: 1, WriteCapacityUnits: 1 },
  TimeToLiveSpecification: { AttributeName: 'timetolive', Enabled: true },
  TableName: 'mytablename'
}
```

Error :

```
UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'TimeToLiveSpecification' found in params
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should **remove** `timetolive` from `AttributeDefinitions`. `AttributeDefinitions` are only for attributes used in your hash or sort keys in your primary table and its indices. So it should be:

```
{
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: 'foo', AttributeType: 'S' },
    { AttributeName: 'baar', AttributeType: 'N' }
  ],
  KeySchema: [
    { AttributeName: 'foo', KeyType: 'HASH' },
    { AttributeName: 'baar', KeyType: 'RANGE' }
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: { ReadCapacityUnits: 1, WriteCapacityUnits: 1 },
  TimeToLiveSpecification: { AttributeName: 'timetolive', Enabled: true },
  TableName: 'mytablename'
}
```

Comment: Did you test this answer? The error he got was *not* about AttributeDefinitions, it was about the unsupported TimeToLiveSpecification. Indeed, the CreateTable operation does not have this option. You need to create the table and only then chose the TTL attribute with the UpdateTimeToLive operation.

Comment: This solution does not work. AFAIK, you need to choose the TTL attribute using the UpdateTimeToLive method. As Nadav has pointed out.